# Gossipsub scalability in terms of topic size

Tags: libp2p

I am currently developing an experimental identity protocol on top libp2p gossipsub(https://idp2p.github.io/). The protocol assumes each identity is a topic to subsribe. Whenever an identity is created, a topic should be created for that identity(per identity per topic). So you can guess there should be created a lot of topic dynamically.

I wonder if libp2p gossipsub protocol is scalable for this kind of use case.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found an answer? LibP2P official documentation says that "Topics can have enormous numbers of subscribers and handle a large throughput of messages", but don't say anything about number of topics. Thanks

Comment: @YerayRodriguez I asked that question on the libp2p matrix chat. Here is answer: ```if you dont subscribe to a topic it has no effect so it comes down to how many identities you are tracking. also note there are some potential issues with the size of the hello packet. there is an open issue in go-libp2p-pubsub discussing solutions for supernodes in a similar setting.```